# Index out of range when reading with Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to open a .xlsx file with Openpyxl, using the "Optimized reader" tips from the documentation :

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename = r'/path/to/the/file.xlsx', use_iterators = True)
```

This give me the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    wb = load_workbook(filename = r'/path/to/the/file.xlsx', use_iterators = True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 151, in load_workbook
    _load_workbook(wb, archive, filename, read_only, keep_vba)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 240, in _load_workbook
    wb._named_ranges = list(read_named_ranges(archive.read(ARC_WORKBOOK), wb))
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/workbook.py", line 160, in read_named_ranges
     named_range.scope = workbook.worksheets[int(location_id)]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I also tried using flags `(keep_vba = True|False, guess_types = True|False, data_only = True|False)` with every combination. Same error.

The .xlsx file I am trying to open has 13 worksheets, there is no worksheet with more than 200 row, so I suppose this is not a size problem.
I can't edit anything on this .xlsx file, I don't have permission, this is a readonly file for me.

I am using Python 2.6 on a Debian Squeeze 64 bits and the version of Openpyxl is 2.1.0.
If I try to open an other file (an empty test file), it works fine (no error triggered, the script carry on).

So I suppose the question is : what is wrong with the .xlsx file I am trying to open ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the defined names / ranges in use. I've seen it an another file but not yet sure quite what's triggering it. Can you please submit a bug, preferably with a sample file, as this will make tracking the problem down a lot easier.

The 2.1 branch should contain a fix for this if you can try a checkout. As far as I can tell the issue is related to the use of defined names from other workbooks or when using some of the reserved names for print areas, etc. Such definitions are likely lost when the file is processed by openpyxl but shouldn't affect the data itself

Comment: The relevant file is the only one I want to work with, so I can't use an exception. I can't give you a sample file because this file contains a lot of important information about m y company and we don't want to share it. I can tell you that there are links in the files, several worksheets and some variables. If I clean all of them (just one sheet without links and without variables, I can work fine with that file).

Comment: Okay, I thought as much. The issue seems to be related to the support in 2.1 for links to external files. I've created a bug and have one sample file but without more knowledge this is going to be difficult to solve. See https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issue/369/indexerror-reading-ranges

You can add the workaround if you need it not to your own code but as a patch to the library. It's not elegant but letting us know if it works will hopefully help us fix the problem.